# Prevent user from coming back to log-in page after logging-in in an Android Application

Tags: android, authentication

I am making an Application which has Log-in form, so what i need is to make user enter His username and password only once means after entering all details once there will be no need to re-enter details again else he log-out. I reached to a point where i can save data in shared preferences but what i want is that my application run logging-in when restart

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After the user successfully logged in, store his information in your Preferences.

For example, to store the username :

```
private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("User", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("username", your_user_name);
editor.commit();
```

Each time the user accesses the login activity, you can check if the username is already stored in the preferences :

```
if (mPreferences.contains("username")) {
    // start Main activity
} else {
    // ask him to enter his credentials
}
```

When the user logs out, don't forget to delete the username key from your preferences :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
editor.clear();   // This will delete all your preferences, check how to delete just one
editor.commit();
```

In you AndroidManifest.xml, you can alos add this line, so the user can't go back to the login page :

```
<activity
    android:name="your login activity"
    android:noHistory="true" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Another way to achive this (but only in case you want to force user login each time he launches application) is to create Application singleton and store credentials there. But approach with SharedPreferences is better in my opinion

Comment: @jbihan All works well ! but it saves username and password for one time only not permanently.  Is there any way to save them permanently?

Comment: Information stored in SharedPreferences are stored permanently, unless you uninstall your application or you delete them in the code.

Comment: but in my case , when i restart my application 3rd time it demands username and password again?

Comment: Are you sure you don't delete the key at some place ? The information should be there. Have you tried to debug it (each place where you use the sharedpreferences ?)

Comment: Ahaaa, thanks for `noHistory` clue. It's been a year I develop login app but I always got `LoginActivity` once I pressed back button in my `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

Create your main activity and check if the user is logged in. If he's not logged in redirect your user to the login page (and finish the other activity otherwise the user can hit the return button to go back to your main activity).

If you do it this way, your user doesn't have to load 2 screens when he's logged in what decreases the boot time.

Comment: can you help me with some sought of example , as right now am confused.